# Why am i getting the result expected in scapy?

Tags: python, scapy

```
import scapy.all as scapy

p = scapy.sniff(filter='tcp', count=1)
d = p.show()

print(scapy.hexraw(d))
```

RESULT:

```
AttributeError: module 'scapy.all' has no attribute 'hexraw'
```

Why am i getting this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hexraw` is a method of the `PacketList` class not a function of `scapy.all`.  Moreover, the `show` method of the `Packet` class returns `None`: it prints something to the standard output but does not return anything.  So doing `d = p.show()` does not make any sense.  I don't know what your goal initially was, but you could try instead:

```py
p.show()  # print the packet list
p[0].show()  # print the first packet of the list
p.hexraw() # print a summary of the packet list with Raw layers being hexdumped
```